# How can I wrap the HTTP Request in a Success or Failure using the Task<IResult>?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm using the HttpRequestMessage and HttpResponseMessage to obtain results from an API. For fault handling I would like to wrap it in a Success or Failure. The results come back from Task What is a good way to do this?

Comment: I think you're looking for Monads. Google Option monad, Either monad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HttpResponseMessage model has a property called `IsSuccessStatusCode` which if `true`, indicates the HTTP response was successful (status codes 200-299).

You *can* write your own wrapper around HttpResponseMessage but why?

You don't need a wrapper in this case if all you need is a way to know if the response has succeeded or not.

Reference: [MSDN - HttpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.http.httpresponsemessage.issuccessstatuscode)

Comment: In what cases would a HttpResponseMessage wrapper be a good practice or use?

Comment: @JustJ It may be a good idea if you are writing an abstraction wrapper for an API that you need to consume, which doesn't have an SDK already - that'd be a good scenario to add in a wrapper to handle mapping, error handling etc.

In this case, it'd be extra, unneeded code to write a wrapper for error handling, hope that helps.